# With Julia Symbolics, how can I do a mathematical summation?

Tags: julia

I am using Symbolics.jl and I want to make a mathematical summation, equivalent to the function Sum from Sympy (https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/concrete.html)

The documentation of Symbolics.jl suggests that it is possible:

> - Discrete math (representations of summations, products, binomial coefficients, etc.)

However, in the frequently asked questions, the opposite is suggested:

> Loops are allowed, but the amount of loop iterations should not require that you know the value of the symbol x.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `+(x...)` for a summation for a vector of symbols.

```
julia> @variables x[1:5]
1-element Vector{Symbolics.Arr{Num, 1}}:
 x[1:5]

julia> +(x...)
x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5]

julia> Symbolics.derivative(+(x...), x[2])
1
```

Beware of `sum(x)` as it seems to be not expanded and yields incorrect results:

```
julia> sum(x)
Symbolics._mapreduce(identity, +, x, Colon(), (:init => false,))

julia> Symbolics.derivative(sum(x), x[2])
0
```

Last but not least, make another step and define the summation symbol to get a nice experience:

```
julia> ∑(v) = +(v...)
∑ (generic function with 1 method)

julia> ∑(x)
x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5]

julia> Symbolics.derivative(100∑(x), x[2])
100
```

Answer (score 12):

It extends Julia itself, so there really isn't much to document: just use Julia on the symbolic values. Thus here, just use `sum`, which is part of [Base Julia](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.sum).

```
julia> using Symbolics

julia> @variables x[1:5]
1-element Vector{Symbolics.Arr{Num, 1}}:
 x[1:5]

julia> x = collect(x)
5-element Vector{Num}:
 x[1]
 x[2]
 x[3]
 x[4]
 x[5]

julia> sum(x)
x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5]
```

> "Loops are allowed, but the amount of loop iterations should not require that you know the value of the symbol x."

That's also a limitation of SymPy, or any other symbolic tracing system because  that restricts to symbolically-reprsentable (quasi-static) codes. This is discussed in more depth in [this blog post](https://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/useful-algorithms-that-are-not-optimized-by-jax-pytorch-or-tensorflow/).

Comment: why am I getting `Symbolics._mapreduce(identity, +, x, Colon(), (:init => false,))` when trying to do `sum(x)`. Now I know I can do `sum(collect(x))` but this looks kind of weird.

Comment: It's converting from a Symbolic Array to an array of Symbols. The Symbolic Array keeps the operation lazy (though with a nasty way of printing it, that IMO is worth an issue) so it has an O(1) representation of the operation. `collect(x)` gives an array of scalar symbols which it then calls sum on. That's an O(n) representation, like SymPy. Symbolic Arrays are just not a completed functionality at this point.